# Detect 404 before headers are sent

Tags: 404-error

I've a piece of code that shows a banner the first time a user visits, then sets a cookie, which prevents it showing again.

However, if the page has a 404 error, the 404 page of the requested resource sets the cookie and the banner is not shown. Checking `is_404()` on the init hook does not avoid this situation.

So how do I correct this problem and detect the 404 on the init hook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Use a later action hook

You cannot use [Conditional Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) before the `posts_selection` hook has run (as per the codex), which happens right after `pre_get_posts` and quite a bit after `init`.

Hence, would it not be easier to set the cookie at a later stage of the request, rather than attempting to detect the 404 earlier (which, off the bat, I would not know how)?

The [`wp`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp) action, for instance, should be early enough.
If I understand you correctly, you should basically be able to set the cookie at the very end of the request, since it becomes relevant on the following request only anyway.

### [Further Info] How do Conditional Tags work?

Conditional Tags depend on the query object's (instance of [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)) public "query type" boolean properties, which by default are set to `false` (see [wp-includes/query.php, Lines 1008 ff. [as of 3.5.1]](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/query.php#L1008)).
These properties are populated with the correct values in `WP_Query`'s [`parse_query`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/query.php#L1419) method, which runs right before `pre_get_posts` (see [wp-includes/query.php, Lines 1907 ff. [as of 3.5.1]](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/query.php#L1907)).

Hence, even though the codex suggests differently, Conditional Tags *should* (not vouching for it, though) actually already be usable in `pre_get_posts` callbacks.
Definitely not earlier though - `init` is out of the question.

Comment: I'm just wondering, do you mean `is_admin(), is_page(),  is_home(), ...` should not work in a `pre_get_posts` hook? thanks

Comment: The codex would suggest so, @birgire, but looking at the source, they should be usable just then. See the updated answer.

Comment: +1 for checking this out ;-) The Codex is somewhat confusing on this matter, because on this page http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts  the conditional tags are used within the `pre_get_posts` hook. Thanks again.

Comment: is_admin should work, but is_page etc are dependent on the query variables of the current active query, which if you're doing pre_get_posts, have just been handed to you via the filter anyway.

Comment: I shall ammend my code to use the 'wp' action